# How to implement emoji in my Android Application?

Tags: android, keyboard, emoji

I created a keyboard application, in that Application I like to insert emoji Icons. Can you please send me a link or explain shortly how to do

Comment: https://github.com/rockerhieu/emojicon

Comment: Did you get anywhere with this?